# Como fazer o quasar enviar arquivos grandes com multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Ola, uma ajuda estou desenvolvendo um app com quasar porem ao criar um upload de arquivo com o component  não consigo enviar os arquivos em partes pequenas...

olha o codigo...

```
<template>
  <q-uploader
    multiple
    auto-expand
    :headers="{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}"
    url=""
    :upload-factory="uploadFile"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Uploader',
  methods: {
    uploadFile (file, updateProgress) {
      // "file" is an Object containing file's props, including content

      // for updating progress (as 0-1 floating number), we need to call:
      // updateProgress (bytesTransferred / totalBytes)

      this.uploadFilesSend({'file': file, 'type': file.type}).then(console.log('upload ok'))

      // we need to return a Promise
      // (resolves when upload is done, rejects when there's an error)
    },
    ...mapActions('uploads', {
      uploadFilesSend: 'create'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Estou usando como servidor o feathersjs com conexão socket.io, o servidor reclama que quando envio um arquivo grande o timeout, da pra até aumentar esse time mais verifiquei que ele esta tentando mandar apenas como um arquivo inteiro e não em partes....

Gostaria de saber se tem e como ativar esse método multipart/form-data..

Agradecido